# Usecase for Task dependency

Tags: uml, task, use-case

I am working on a task management application and need to address all the usecases for task dependency for different dependencies:

1. Start to Start
2. Start to Finish
3. Finish to Start
4. Finish to Finish

One of the usecases I found was that we need to make sure if Task A has Task B as its dependency and Task B has Task C as its dependency and Task C has Task A as its dependency then we should not allow as it leads to a cycle.

Could I get some help where I can find all the different usecases with Task Dependency.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple constraint. You can express it by attaching a note and placing the text in curly brackets (and eventually stereotyping the note as`<<invariant>>`). The text could be

```
`{ cyclic dependencies are not allowed }`
```